# CSV to Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, data-structures

For homework we have been asked to build a dictionary from CSV (without importing CSV or any other lib, only using built in Python functions).

CSV looks something like this:

```
Class mate, distance1, distance2, distance3, distance4
Bob, 102.5, 0.5587, 45.77, 49.225
Sally, 785.115, 32145.01, 4578.25, 0.5587
Anne, 4521.87, 12.5, 0.2547, 1545.554
...
...
...
```

I keep getting value errors and not much further.

```
race_read = open('student_guess.csv', 'r')
race_open = race_read.readlines()

race_dict = {}

for line in race_open:
    key, val = line.strip().split('\n')
    race_dict[int(key)] = val

    print(race_dict)
```

Here are the final two lines of the traceback I get:

```
key, val = line.strip().split('\n')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I am expecting the dictionary to look like this:

```
{'Bob': [102.5, 0.5587, 45.77, 49.225], 'Sally': [785.115, .... etc], etc}
```

Comment: Given that the new line character is at the end of the line, and you've just stripped it, how many items did you expect to be in the split list?

Comment: I expected there to be 4 items in the split list with the name as the key.

Comment: Why *four*? Did you check whether that's true? And if there *were* four, how would assigning that to two names work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code and some suggestions:

- You are splitting on newline `\n`, which is at the end of a line, so you will only get one item in your list. You cannot extract two items out of it, hence you get the `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` error
- You need to split on `,` instead of `\n`, since the values are separate by a `,`
- You can use the `with` context manager to open the file
- You need to skip the first line of the file using `next()`
- You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to output the name and values and then create the dictionary

Putting all these together, the refactored code might look like

```
race_dict = {}

#Use with to open the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as race_read:

    #Skip the first line
    next(race_read)

    #Read all lines in a list
    race_open = race_read.readlines()

    #Iterate through the list
    for line in race_open:
        #Extract names and float values by splitting on ,
        key, *val = line.strip().split(',')

        #Convert all strings in val to float
        race_dict[key] = list(map(float, val))

print(race_dict)
```

So if the input file is

```
Class mate, distance1, distance2, distance3, distance4
Bob, 102.5, 0.5587, 45.77, 49.225
Sally, 785.115, 32145.01, 4578.25, 0.5587
Anne, 4521.87, 12.5, 0.2547, 1545.554
```

The output will be

```
{'Bob': [102.5, 0.5587, 45.77, 49.225], 
'Sally': [785.115, 32145.01, 4578.25, 0.5587], 
'Anne': [4521.87, 12.5, 0.2547, 1545.554]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter in your file is comma so - first you need to split by comma -

```
res = line.strip().split(',')
```

This will give you a tuple of 5 strings -

```
'Bob', '102.5', '0.5587', '45.77', '49.225'
```

If you want to add them to the dictionary as you described you will have to do the following -

```
race_dic[res[0]] = [float(res[1]), float(res[2]), float(res[3]), float(res[4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
race_read = open('student_guess.csv', 'r')
race_open = race_read.readlines()

race_dict = {}
count = 0
for line in race_open:
    if count==0:
        count = 1
        continue
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    race_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
print(race_dict)
```

Output

```
{'Anne': [' 4521.87', ' 12.5', ' 0.2547', ' 1545.554'],
'Bob': [' 102.5', ' 0.5587', ' 45.77', ' 49.225'],
'Sally': [' 785.115', ' 32145.01', ' 4578.25', ' 0.5587']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zarmey,

The corrected code may look like this:

```
for line in race_open[1:]: # 1
    splitline = line.split(',') # 2
    splitline = [s.strip() for s in splitline] # 3
    key, val = splitline[0], splitline[1:] # 4
    val = [float(v) for v in val] # 5
    race_dict[key] = val
print(race_dict)
```

1. iterate race_open from 2d line if you don't need titles.
2. you should split your lines not at line break '\n' but at comma. use split(',').
3. strip after splitting.
4. when building dict, provide sublist of all but first 
   item as value [1:].
5. convert numeric values to float after you split them out from names

output:

```
{'Bob': [102.5, 0.5587, 45.77, 49.225], 'Sally': [785.115, 32145.01, 4578.25, 0.5587], 'Anne': [4521.87, 12.5, 0.2547, 1545.554]}
```